# Find integral $\int \frac {x^3}{a^2-x^2}dx$

Tags: integration

Need help with amateur integral $$\int \frac {x^3}{a^2-x^2}dx$$ I know that i need $x^3$ place under the differential sign, but then i got stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: $$x^3=x(x^2-a^2)+xa^2$$ and $$\dfrac{2x}{x^2-a^2}=\dfrac{1}{x-a}+\dfrac{1}{x+a}$$

Answer (score 2):

Using partial fraction. We can write 
$$\frac{x^3}{a^2-x^2}=Ax+\frac{B}{a-x}+\frac{C}{a+x}$$
for some constants $A,B$ and $C$. Then you can integrate for each term.

Answer (score 0):

use the $u$- substitution $u^2 = a^2 - x^2, u\, du = x \, dx$ to transform 
$$\int \frac{x^3 \, dx}{a^2 - x^2} = \int \frac{(a^2 - u^2) u \, du}{u^2} 
= \int (\frac{a^2}{u} - u)\, du = a^2 \ln u -\frac12 u^2 + C$$

Answer (score 0):

$a^2-x^2=t$

$-2xdx=dt$

$$\int\frac{x^2.xdx}{a^2-x^2}=-\int \frac{(a^2-t)dt}{2t}$$

Can u do it now?